# DateFormat for ISO8601 string with TimeZone?

Tags: date-and-time

What is the `DateFormat` to convert ISO8601 string with timezone to `DateObject`?

For exmaple,

```
DateObject["2022-10-01T00:00:00.000+00:00", 
 DateFormat -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", "T", "Hour24", ":", 
   "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "Millisecond", "+", "TimeZone"}]
```

throws:

> DateObject::str: String 2022-10-01T00:00:00.000+00:00 cannot be
> interpreted as a date.

with +0000 (valid ISO alternative) fails. Removing "+" from DateFormat fails. But works without timezone:

```
DateObject["2022-10-01T00:00:00.000", 
 DateFormat -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", "T", "Hour24", ":", 
   "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "Millisecond"}]
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with V13.1, and it appears to create a valid DateObject. What version are you using?

Comment: Hmm. I can reproduce it with these, however: "2022-10-01T00:00:00.000+07", "2022-10-01T00:00:00.000+7", "2022-10-01T00:00:00.000+0700".

Comment: Both of these work: "2022-10-01T00:00:00.000+Z", "2022-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"

Comment: First example returns: 2022-10-01T01:00:00.000+TimeZoneGMT+1;
Second example returns: 2022-10-01T00:00:00.000GMT+1.
On Mac, MMA version 13.0.0.